# Как красиво скрыть текст под плавным фоном в виде градиента?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите как правильно реализовать скрытые текста под фоном, чтобы было видно что ниже или выше есть текст с плавным градиентом

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 8px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(#fff, transparent);
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent, #fff);
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
```

Comment: Правильно - никак. А чтобы абсолютно позиционированные элементы не скроллились - просто добавлением еще одного вложенного элемента, и переносом свойства `overflow` в его стили (следует учесть что градиенты при этом будут поверх скроллбаров. Чтобы этого избежать, потребуется еще один промежуточный слой вложенности...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

div::before,
div::after {
  background: linear-gradient(#fff, transparent);
  content: '';
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

div::before {
  background: linear-gradient(transparent, #fff);
  bottom: 0;
}

p {
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Чисто эстетически, вместо <p> просится элемент с понятным по смыслу именем класса. И оставить тем самым возможность деления текста на абзацы.